# Refine (filter) search results without URL change

Tags: php, search, filter

I am developing a travel website in php. Users can perform searches to get rates for hotels in particular locations.

What I want to find out is the most suitable method to build a filtering system.

Users should be able to filter the results for instance just to see 5 Start hotels with wifi facility or 4 and 5 start hotels in a particular area.

The below is a working example

http://www.wego.com/hotels/united-kingdom/london/20120810/20120811/8168849

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would look to use JavaScript to sort or filter results. I've had good luck with [TinySort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/).

EDIT: Alternatively you could use an AJAX call to refresh the pages content without redirecting.